# Tal condition always evaluates to false

Tags: plone, zope

I'm using plone and trying to display a form result in a page template.

I'm trying to filter some database results using `tal:condition` with a python expression but it always evaluates to false.

The code looks like this:

```
 <tr tal:repeat="result view/results">
     <td> <span tal:condition="python:view.teams[0]==result.team_id" tal:replace="result/position">Position</span></td>
     <td> <span tal:condition="python:view.teams[1]==result.team_id" tal:replace="result/position">Position</span></td>
</tr>
```

I want the table cells to be filled with the team position when the team id is matched in the result, but the cells always are empty. 
If I remove the `tal:condition` from the `span` and replace the `tal:replace="result/position"` with `tal:replace=python:view.teams[0]==result.team_id` it prints `True` or `False` so I can check that the result is correct.

Can anyone help me about this issue? Why does `tal:condition` allways evaluate false?

Comment: Are you certain that result/position actually returns a value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd fully expect this to work, so something else must be wrong.

Python expressions such as yours are commonplace; there are [several](https://github.com/Jarn/collective.solr/blob/master/src/collective/solr/browser/errors.pt#L21) [examples](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.controlpanel/blob/master/plone/app/controlpanel/types.pt#L61) [on](http://www.catapultsolutions.net/resources/tal-condition-based-on-url-in-a-plone-site.html) [the](http://www.scips.worc.ac.uk/documentation/page_template_design.html) [internet](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/internationalization-i18n-and-localization-l10n/language-selector) to show they do normally work.

Try further debugging the values with `tal:replace="python:repr(view.teams)"` and `tal:replace="python:repr(result.team_id)"` statements and similar to be 100% certain of what your data structures look like.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried debugging as you suggested and then I realized in the error: `view.teams` was an integer array while `team_id` was a string. Just cast `team_id` and then it started working perfect.